# android google maps Error inflating class fragment - tried all solutions I could find

Tags: android, android-fragments, maps

I've been trying to add Google Maps to my app but keep getting an error. I know this topic is all over stackOverflow but I've tried almost everything and I'm thinking there must be something I'm not seeing. Please understand I've tried all the solutions on stackoverflow. if you could please try and look for me and let me know if there's something I'm not doing correctly, I'd appreciate it alot :)

My MapActivity:

```
public class MapActivity  extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback{

    TextView temperature, forecast, clouds, wind, humidity;
    Switch mySwitch;
    String switchChosen;

    //all of these variables are used for pulling data from the database
    InputStream is=null;
    String result=null;
    String line=null;

    JSONObject jsonObj;

    ArrayList<String> items;

    ProgressDialog pDialog;


    AutoCompleteTextView enterCity;
    String[] languages={"Johannesburg","Tokyo","Pretoria","Rome","London","Mumbai", "Chicago", "Berlin", "Osaka", "Philadelphia", "Shanghai", "Zurich"};
    Button okButton;


    GoogleMap mMap;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_map);

        temperature = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView_temperature);
        forecast = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView_forecast);
        clouds = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView_clouds);
        wind = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView_wind);
        humidity = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView_humidity);


        enterCity=(AutoCompleteTextView)findViewById(R.id.autoCompleteTextView1);
        ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,languages);
        enterCity.setAdapter(adapter);
        enterCity.setThreshold(1);

        okButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button_ok);
        okButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                //check if there is network connection
                if (isNetworkConnected()) {
                    new getWeather().execute();
                } else if (!isNetworkConnected()) {
                    if (pDialog.isShowing()) {
                        pDialog.dismiss();
                    }
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please Connect To A Network.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }

        });


        mySwitch = (Switch)findViewById(R.id.switch1);

        mySwitch.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,
                                         boolean isChecked) {


                //check if there is network connection
                if (isNetworkConnected()) {
                    new getWeather().execute();
                } else if (!isNetworkConnected()) {
                    if (pDialog.isShowing()) {
                        pDialog.dismiss();
                    }
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please Connect To A Network.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }

            }
        });


        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);




    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;

        // Add a marker in Sydney, Australia, and move the camera.
        LatLng sydney = new LatLng(-34, 151);
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(sydney).title("Marker in Sydney"));
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(sydney));

    }


    class getWeather extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {

            super.onPreExecute();
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

            Log.v("result", getData());

            try {


                jsonObj = new JSONObject(getData());
                Log.v("jsonObj", jsonObj.toString());



            } catch (JSONException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


            return null;
        }
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);

            try {

                Log.v("j.get", jsonObj.get("coord").toString());




                temperature.setText(jsonObj.getJSONObject("main").getString("temp"));
                forecast.setText(jsonObj.get("coord").toString());
                clouds.setText(jsonObj.getJSONObject("clouds").getString("all") + " %");
                wind.setText(jsonObj.getJSONObject("wind").getString("deg"));
                humidity.setText(jsonObj.getJSONObject("main").getString("humidity") + " %");



            } catch (JSONException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    }



    public String getData()
    {

        //check the current state of the switch before we call the URL
        if(mySwitch.isChecked()){
            switchChosen = "metric";
        }
        else {
            switchChosen = "imperial";
        }


        try {
            URL url = new URL("http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=" + enterCity.getText() + "&units=" + switchChosen + "&APPID=cc5dd2bb37b95fcf31f3343ea7285c3f");
            HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            try {
                BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(urlConnection.getInputStream()));
                StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
                String line;
                while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                    stringBuilder.append(line).append("\n");
                }
                bufferedReader.close();
                return stringBuilder.toString();
            }
            finally{
                urlConnection.disconnect();
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e) {
            Log.e("ERROR", e.getMessage(), e);
            return null;
        }

    }


    public boolean isNetworkConnected(){

        boolean connected = true;
        ConnectivityManager cm =
                (ConnectivityManager)getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo netInfo = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        if (netInfo != null && netInfo.isConnected() && netInfo.isAvailable()) {
            //Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "connected.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            connected= true;
        }else{
            connected= false;
            //Toast.makeText(getActivity(), " Not connected.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        return connected;
    }





    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_login, menu);


        return true;
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {



            case R.id.action_settings:

                return true;

            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }


}
```

My activity_map.xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >






    <fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" />



</RelativeLayout>
```

My AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.jared.myweatherapp">

    <permission
        android:name="app.me.locationalarm.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />

    <uses-permission android:name="app.me.locationalarm.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <!-- Required to show current location -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

    <!-- Required OpenGL ES 2.0. for Maps V2 -->
    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true" />
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
        android:value="AIzaSyBADcadXXgzNxQBau1LQsKeFBXRmSuJLss" />




    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name=".LoginActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".MapActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_map"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
        <!--
             ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to add Google Play services to your project for
             App Indexing.  See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
        -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

        <activity
            android:name=".RegisterActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_register"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"></activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

My Logcat:

```
04-28 09:20:46.301 3727-3727/com.example.jared.myweatherapp E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                              Process: com.example.jared.myweatherapp, PID: 3727
                                                                              java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.jared.myweatherapp/com.example.jared.myweatherapp.MapActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #24: Binary XML file line #141: Error inflating class fragment
                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2416)
                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
                                                                                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
                                                                                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                                                                                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
                                                                               Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #24: Binary XML file line #141: Error inflating class fragment
                                                                                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:539)
                                                                                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
                                                                                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374)
                                                                                  at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:393)
                                                                                  at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:2166)
                                                                                  at com.example.jared.myweatherapp.MapActivity.onCreate(MapActivity.java:83)
                                                                                  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237)
                                                                                  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107)
                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369)
                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
                                                                                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
                                                                                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
                                                                                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616) 
                                                                               Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #141: Error inflating class fragment
                                                                                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:782)
                                                                                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704)
                                                                                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:835)
                                                                                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798)
                                                                                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(LayoutInflater.java:971)
                                                                                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:831)
                                                                                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798)
                                                                                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515)
                                                                                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423) 
                                                                                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374) 
                                                                                  at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:393) 
                                                                                  at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:2166) 
                                                                                  at com.example.jared.myweatherapp.MapActivity.onCreate(MapActivity.java:83) 
                                                                                  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237) 
                                                                                  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107) 
                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369) 
                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
                                                                                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
                                                                                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
                                                                                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616) 
                                                                               Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: API key not found.  Check that <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY" android:value="your API key"/> is in the <application> element of AndroidManifest.xml
                                                                                  at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.c.ad.a(Unknown Source)
                                                                                  at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.a.e.a(Unknown Source)
                                                                                  at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.CreatorImpl.b(Unknown Source)
                                                                                  at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.CreatorImpl.b(Unknown Source)
                                                                                  at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.h.onTransact(SourceFile:62)
                                                                                  at android.os.Binder.transact(Binder.java:387)
                                                                                  at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.ah.b(SourceFile:179)
                                                                                  at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.CreatorImpl.b(SourceFile:100)
                                                                                  at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.ag.onTransact(SourceFile:62)
                                                                                  at android.os.Binder.transact(Binder.java:387)
                                                                                  at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.zzc$zza$zza.zzs(Unknown Source)
                                                                                  at com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment$zzb.zzzW(Unknown Source)
                                                                                  at com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment$zzb.zza(Unknown Source)
                                                                                  at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.zza.zza(Unknown Source)
                                                                                  at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.zza.onInflate(Unknown Source)
                                                                                  at com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment.onInflate(Unknown Source)
                                                                                  at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.onInflate(Fragment.java:1142)
                                                                                  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.onCreateView(FragmentManager.java:2287)
                                                                                  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentController.onCreateView(FragmentController.java:120)
                                                                                  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.dispatchFragmentsOnCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:357)
                                                                                at android.support
```

Thank you very much

Comment: Please insert the stack trace of the exception as well.

Comment: Thank you @Blehi . I added it in :) my mistake :)

Comment: Your code looks ok. It seems to me that the problem is with yout API key. `Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: API key not found.  Check that <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY" android:value="your API key"/> is in the <application> element of AndroidManifest.xml`